# Store Users Coordinates from google maps into Firebase Database

Tags: ios, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, heatmap

I have been working with google heat maps for some time now and I am trying to store the user's location along with some other items in firebase, then show them on google maps. I have been researching this method but for some reason, the code I enter does not store the user's location but does store all of the other information such as job image, job category, job bio and price.  I was wondering if someone could help me correct my code to show how to store users location to firebase.

```
 @objc func handlePost() {
    let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let timestamp = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)
    guard let image = JobImageView.image, let category = JobCategory.text, let description = JobBio.text, let cost = price.text else {
        print("Error")
        return
    }
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid  else {
        return
    }
    let imageName = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("job_images").child("\(imageName).png")

    if let JobImageUrl = self.JobImageView.image, let  uploadData = JobImageUrl.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75) {
        storageRef.putData(uploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, error) in

            if error != nil, metadata != nil {
                print(error ?? "")
                return

            }

            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                if let JobImageUrl = url?.absoluteString {
//if i attempt to store the users location, the line below crashes with the error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
                       let myLocation = self.mapView.myLocation
                    let coords: [String: Double] = [
                        "lat": myLocation!.coordinate.latitude,
                        "long": myLocation!.coordinate.longitude
                    ]
                    let values = ["category": category, "description": description, "cost": cost, "JobImageUrl": JobImageUrl, "fromId": fromId, "timestamp": timestamp, "location": coords] as [String : Any]
                    self.registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
                }
            })
        })
    }
   }


   private func registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://odd-jobs-llc-f854a.firebaseio.com/")
    let usersReference = ref.child("JobPost").child(uid)
    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in

        if err != nil {
            print("err")
            return
        }

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

}
```

Comment: If you print `values.coords` inside `registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID`, what does it show?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Value of type '[String : AnyObject]' has no member 'coords'

Comment: Sorry, that should be printing `values.location`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen same error..

Comment: Interesting. Since you add `location` to the `values` array before calling `registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID`, I'd expect it to print the values you added. Did you do any further investigation? (keep in mind that Stack Overflow is an incredibly inefficient interactive debugger)

Comment: I have been researching this topic for some time now. It just turns out that the only way I can find some answers are through stack. As you said, the answer I find are inefficient

Comment: With the comment trail we've left so far, it seems that you're unable to pass a nested dictionary to a function call. This would have nothing to do with Firebase, meaning you should be able to reproduce the problem with a very small code snippet that any Swift expert would probably be eager to help with. Limiting the number of technologies involved is a great troubleshooting strategy, and the best way to increase your chances of getting help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thank you. Yea I am not an expert. I’m just an individual trying to find a way to save the users location to Firebase

Comment: And I'm trying to help you with that. For example, by explaining why a so-called [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is the best way to get further help.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a direct answer but may lead to one.

The issue is the code posted in your question works as expected. Here's what I did.

First, I wanted to isolate the issue to either a Swift coding error, or a Firebase coding error. I plugged in some test values, commented out the Firebase code and added a couple of print statements within the registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID to see if what prints is the expected data. The output is exactly what was expected, including the two test coords 2.0 and 3.0

```
func testBuildingDataset() {
    let coords: [String: Double] = [
        "lat": 2.0,
        "long": 3.0
    ]
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let category = "some cat"
    let description = "some desc"
    let cost = "some cost"
    let JobImageUrl = "some jobImgUrl"
    let fromId = "some fromId"
    let timestamp = "some timestamp"

    let values = ["category": category, "description": description, "cost": cost, "JobImageUrl": JobImageUrl, "fromId": fromId, "timestamp": timestamp, "location": coords] as [String : Any]
    registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: uid, values: values as [String : AnyObject])
}

func registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    print(uid)
    print(values)
```

The conclusion is the dataset (at least what I provided) was sound and the Swift code is working as expected. I then uncommented the Firebase update function and ran the test again.

```
func registerUserIntoDatabseWithUID(uid: String, values: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let usersReference = self.ref.child("JobPost").child(uid)
    usersReference.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
        if err != nil {
            print("err")
            return
        }
        //self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}
```

and then checked my Firebase. The written data is exactly as expected.

```
"JobPost" : {
    "uid_0" : {
      "JobImageUrl" : "some jobImgUrl",
      "category" : "some cat",
      "cost" : "some cost",
      "description" : "some desc",
      "fromId" : "some fromId",
      "location" : {
        "lat" : 2,
        "long" : 3
      },
      "timestamp" : "some timestamp"
    }
  },
```

This leads to an overall conclusion that the code in the question works, and the issue lies outside that code.

This is the key

> //if i attempt to store the users location, the line below crashes
>   with the error  //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while
>   unwrapping an Optional value

```
let myLocation = self.mapView.myLocation
```

So the issue is that either the mapView is nil or myLocation is nil

However, that code was not included in the question so no way to investigate it further. Additionally, that error could be caught by working with your optionals in a safe fashion

```
guard let myMap = self.mapView else {
   print("the mapview was nil")
   return
}
//use myMap from here as as you know it's not nil
```

Also, if mapView is a MKMapView, it doesn't have a myLocation property, only a userLocation property so it's apparently a custom class, which should also be included in the question.

Hope that helps.

Comment: after using your method, I have found that location is nil. Is there a way for me to fix this? I tried the guard let method and it till returned nil and won't save the users location.

Comment: also I am using GMSMapView not MkMapView

Comment: @zachwilcox You may be mis-diagnosing the issue. It's not that Firebase won't save your location; the location data you are telling Firebase to save is nil (Per my answer), so the problem is unrelated to Firebase and directly related to your mapView object. You should examine how the mapView object is populated before the code in your question is called. Maybe posting a separate question that includes how your GMSMapView mapView object is populated to see where the issue lies - maybe it's going out of scope before the code in your question is called?

Comment: yea I realized that! When I i comment out ”let myLocation = self.mapView.myLocation and change the lat and long to have numbers it saves. The problem lies within the mapView being nil. I guess I understand why that it is but I’m not too sure how to fix it. The reason it’s nil is because in this particular viewController, there is no maps. I have two view controllers one is the googlemapsview and the other is a post controller. I’m thinking I have to initiate google maps?

Comment: @zachwilcox It looks like you have a class var property representing the mapObject *self.mapView* so from wherever the map data is initially created you can pass it into your class so you can get to it's properties. You don't need to have a map tied to *this* viewController but the data has to come from somewhere so just pass it in.

Comment: private var mapView: GMSMapView! is the only other references to the code I have in this view controller. Do I need to create Func didUpdateLocations as well?

Comment: how would I go about passing in this data?

Comment: @zachwilcox There's a lot of ways to do that but passing data between classes goes beyond the scope of this particular question. There are a number of questions here on SO about how to implement GMSMapView so that's a good place to start. I would suggest reviewing those and then crafting a new question specific to your use case.